# Azure, where did "Incoming client certificates" option go?

Tags: azure, ssl, web-applications

I configured my function app to expect certificates from clients. I don't see that option in Azure Portal today. Do you have any idea what happened all of a sudden?

[image: Azure Incoming Client Certificates option not found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I think it was due to portal update. It is available now again.

[Current Azure Portal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlh90.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, now the option is moved under Settings -> Configuration -> General Settings -> Require Incoming Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the "Bindings" tab, just switch to  Private Key Certificate or Public Key Certificate:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thiago. This option doesnt force the incoming certificate. It used to be something like this till yesterday.[link](https://imgur.com/knx5FJd.png)

Comment: I assume once you configure it, then it will be used for the encryption. I mean, there's no need to enforce, any https request will be encrypted using it

Comment: Thanks Again. I had configured it couple of days back. It was working fine. Even now it is working as expected(it is expecting client certs). But, the option to turn that off is missing now.